# How to change colors for ":sign" area in VIM?

Tags: vim

VIM supports :sign command that is widely used in debuggers to display graphical breakpoints to the left. How can i find correct names for background and foreground colors of this area in order to change them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `SignColumn` highlight group.  For future reference, I found this by running `:help highlight`, then running the snippet found there that displays all active highlight groups (pasted here for convenience).

```
:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim
```

Answer (score 1):

The color schemes, to my knowledge best, should be saved in

```
 <home>/.vim/colors
```

folder. Try some schemes [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=color%20scheme&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search)

Comment: I know. Just need the correct name for ":sign" background and foreground colors. Like "StatusLineNC" or whatever. Can't find this color in default color schemes and trying to guess it manually will take lots of time :(